# Add items into DataContext via loop

Tags: c#, wpf, loops, datatemplate, datacontext

I have following code in C#, WPF:

```
base.DataContext = new DataTemplate[]
                {
                    new DataTemplate
                    {
                        lblText = "First",
                        txtBoxContent = ""
                    },

                    new DataTemplate
                    {
                        lblText = "Second",
                        txtBoxContent = "Something"
                    }
                };
```

but i need to fill DataContext dynamically from database. My idea looks like this:

```
base.DataContext = new DataTemplate[]
        {
            for(int i = 0; i< dsTmp.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                new DataTemplate
                {
                    lblText = "Count: ",
                    txtBoxContent = dsTmp.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString();
                }
            }
        };
```

When i type this, it yells some syntax errors on me;

Could anybody tell me, how to write it correctly?

Comment: it would have been very helpful if you would have written the error as well.

Comment: ; expected ////

Invalid expression term 'for'

Comment: I think, the problem is in bad syntax. In my opinion for loop cant be in new DataTemplate[]{}. But i dont know how to write in another way.

Answer (score 3):

You can't have code inside [object initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) syntax. Why not simply do this:

```
   var list = new DataTemplate[dsTmp.Tables[0].Rows.Count];
   for(int i = 0; i< dsTmp.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        var item = new DataTemplate
        {
            lblText = "Count: ",
            txtBoxContent = dsTmp.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString();
        };
        list[i] = item;
    }

    this.DataContext = list;
```

Comment: Or you could use Linq, `this.DataContext=dsTmp.Tables[0].Rows.Select(x=>new DataTemplate { lblText = "Count: ", txtBoxContent=x[0].ToString() }).ToArray();`

Comment: @BobVale nice, I like that :), I will add it the answer if you want :-)... or well just yours :)

Comment: It still writes error "; expected" after ending bracket of new DataTemplate.

Comment: @BeerMaker sorry missing ; after the creation of the new DataTemplate, I will update it.

Comment: @MBen, added as an answer as it was liked :)

Comment: Thank you very much. It works perfect for me! (I have to delete semicolon after line starting with txtBoxContent).

Answer (score 2):

MBen and Habib have already answered why the for is failing, because you can't do a loop in an object initializer and have provided loop alternatives.

Alternatively you can use linq to perform an initialization.

```
this.DataContext=dsTmp.Tables[0].Rows.Select(
  x=>new DataTemplate { 
                        lblText = "Count: ",
                        txtBoxContent=x[0].ToString()
                      }).ToArray();
```

Comment: If you miss out the `.ToArray()` then the datacontext will be an IEnumerable thats not evalutated until the DataContext is.

Comment: You could even slip an `.AsParallel()` in before the `.Select` to use multiple threads to generate the array.

Answer (score 1):

The error that `;` is missing is bit misleading. The actual problem is that you are trying to create an array of DataTemplate with the loop, You can't use loop in array/object initialization. Try the following.

```
DataTemplate[] tempDataTemplate = new DataTemplate[ds.Temp.Tables[0].Rows.Count]();
for(int i = 0; i< dsTmp.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {

             tempDataTemplate[i] =   new DataTemplate
                                             {
                                             lblText = "Count: ",
                                             txtBoxContent = dsTmp.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString();
                                             };
            }

base.DataContext = tempDataTemplate;
```

Answer (score 0):

i dont know what you wanna achieve, but did you ever try mvvm with viewmodel first approach?

create a viewmodel class, e.g. MyData with 2 public properties MyText, MyContent. create a collection of these objects and fill this from your database.

at least you need an itemscontrol with itemssource binding set to your collection and a datatemplate for your MyData object.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyData}">
  <view:MyDataViewControl />
</DataTemplate>
```

now you see all your dynamic objects in your itemscontrol.